# Can't compare = in VHDL with std_logic_vector types

Tags: vhdl

I've tried to work around this and have failed.  Strangely enough, the exact same code in another file of my project seems fine, and I'm using the same libraries.. What's wrong?

Line of code (and the generate that it's inside)

```
generate_decounter_ppl: for i in 0 to ppl - 1 generate
block_decounter_load(i) <= (ppl_stage_count = conv_std_logic_vector((i),log2(ppl)));
```

Error:

```
Line 175: found '0' definitions of operator "=", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for "="
```

Context:

```
ppl : integer := 18;    

ppl_stage_count : in std_logic_vector(log2(ppl)-1 downto 0);

signal block_decounter_load : std_logic_vector(ppl -1 downto 0); 


library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
```

Comment: `use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL; use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;` is your biggest problem. These are non-standard packages. Use `ieee.numeric_std.all` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to do?

As best as I can guess, it looks like you might be confusing VHDL with Verilog or C and are maybe trying to do something like the following:

```
block_decounter_load(i) <= '1' when (ppl_stage_count = conv_std_logic_vector((i),log2(ppl))) else '0';
```

In VHDL, you can't implicitly change types as part of an assignment.  You're trying to convert a boolean result into std_logic in your code.  You have to do this explicitly with a conditional signal assignment (the 'when' clause in my example above) an if statement inside a process, or some other means.

Comment: Charles, I hadn't thought of that. The following does indeed work:  block_decounter_load(i) <= '1' when ((ppl_stage_count = conv_std_logic_vector((i),log2(ppl)))) else '0';

Comment: I had the exact same problem and this solution is exactly on the money - thanks.